# Zf2 multicheckbox at least one element is always required

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form

I can't validate a zf2 form with multicheckbox because at least one checkbox is always required.
I found a lot of reference to this issue (for example here - https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4845), but i didn't found a solution for this.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem ?

UPDATE: I use a doctrine 2 [objectmulticheckbox](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md) which is extended from zf2 multichechbox. As is commented below the override of getInputFilterSpecification method, will solve the problem with form validation, but the values will still remain in database (values populated by objectmulticheckbox).

Answer (score 3):

I found a seemingly easier way to get around this issue by setting the input filter 'required' to false inside the controller, after the form is instantiated.

```
<?php 
    $form = new CampaignForm($multiCheckboxOptions); // Setting up checkbox in form class
    $form->getInputFilter()->get('my_multi_checkbox')->setRequired(false);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `getInputFilterSpecification` function on your form to set the field to not be required. For example:

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
    return array(
    [...]
        'the-multi-checkbox-field' => array(
            'required' => false,
        ),
    [...]
    );
}
```

Comment: Ok I overridden this function. The validation is passed but the values are not removed from database. I use doctrine 2 ObjectMulticheckbox for many to many relation (which is extended from zf2 multicheckbox).
When some values are passed from all works fine and values are saved to database.

Comment: @user2623505 I'm not totally sure what you are asking but it does not seem related to your original question of form validation.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i did a little hack to solve this problem.
So I added this code in the action controller:

```
$form->bind($client);
    /** @var $request Request */
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            /** @var $client Client */
            $client = $form->getData();
            // hack because of - https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4694
            if($request->getPost('reportSettings') === null){
                $client->setReportSettings(null); // set null to remove all associations with this client
            }
```

And also as it is described in the first answere, in form should be rewritten getInputFilterSpecification method, for field that shouldn't be required.